# Catch search view menu item click in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, searchview, android-actionbar-compat

I have an action bar that is attached to my main activity.  There are many different fragments that the activity hosts.  In the action bar there are menu items.  One is a search view.  I have this declared as follows:

menu xml.

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="@string/search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionViewClass= "android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
```

In Main Activity:

```
   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

        SearchManager searchManager =
                (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

The search view works, when I click the icon the search view expands.  I need to capture the click of the search view, as when the user clicks the search view I want to display a view showing the user a list of their recent searches.

I will also be using the search view like so:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search)
            .getActionView();
    if (null != searchView) {
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
                .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    }

    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            // this is your adapter that will be filtered
            return true;
        }

        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            //Here u can get the value "query" which is entered in the search box.

        }
    };
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

and carry out the search when the user types 3 characters or more.

I have tried this in the activity:

```
  @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_search:
                L.i("search", "search");
                return false;


            case android.R.id.home:
                L.i("home", "home pressed");
                break;

            case R.id.action_done:
                L.i("done", "done pressed");
                break;

            default:
                ;;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

It recognises the done menu item but not the search.  I will need to be able to pick up the click in activity and fragment.

So if anyone can point out where I'm going wrong.

Oh, in fragment I've added

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);



@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_search:
                L.i("search", "search");
                return false;


            case android.R.id.home:
                L.i("home", "home pressed");
                break;

            case R.id.action_done:

                //for testing
                checkSelectedInterests();
                //TODO: MLC
                L.i("done", "done pressed");
                break;

            default:
                ;;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

so if anyone can help I'd appreciate it

Answer (score 4):

So I figured this out.  From what I can gather this can't be done via the onOptionsItemSelected method.

So I then set an onclicklistener on the search view which didn't work either.  On closer inspection I needed to set and onSearchClickListener as follows:

```
searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                L.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "SearchViewCLicked");
            }
        });
```

Hopefully that'll help someone out!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple solution to this, set an onActionExpandListener to the menu item as shown below:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        // Get the MenuItem for the action item
        MenuItem actionMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

        // Define the listener
        actionMenuItem.setOnActionExpandListener(new MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                // Do what you want when it expands
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                // Do what you want when it collapses
                return true;
            }
        });

        return true;
    }
```